# AngularJS Batarang - What are interceptedExpressions?

Tags: angularjs, batarang

I'm currently using the AngularJS 1.3.0 stable build and the Batarang Chrome extension. In the watch tree I notice that under many of my scopes there's something called "interceptedExpression". What is that or what scenarios create an interceptedExpression?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

- **What is `interceptedExpression`?**

  `interceptedExpression` is a function returned by [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse).
- **Why its called `interceptedExpression` in Batarang?**

  Because the function declared inside angular source code is a named function called [`interceptedExpression`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L1216).
- **What scenarios create an interceptedExpression?**

  One of the scenarios I know is when you declare a local scope property using `=` in a directive. This will create a `interceptedExpression` record in batarang. See angular src [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L1861).

Comment: what about regularInterceptedExpression?

Comment: is there a way to reduce this is the case of the directives using ```=```?

Comment: or a oneTimeInterceptedExpression

Comment: I think the only way to reduce it is by reducing the number of properties nested within $scope in your controller.