# What is regularInterceptedExpression in angular?

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-digest

During debugging of my ng-app I've find out that most time of $digest takes regularInterceptedExpression. The question is, what is causes of triggering it?

Comment: There is another Stack Overflow question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363286/angularjs-batarang-what-are-interceptedexpressions or more in depth: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/607sICcxqsM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Batarang - What are interceptedExpressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363286/angularjs-batarang-what-are-interceptedexpressions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363286/angularjs-batarang-what-are-interceptedexpressions

Answer (score 0):

Found this on AngularJs Docs, hope this can help.

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22

Following scenarios could cause this error.

1. When you declare a local scope property using = in a directive. This will create a interceptedExpression.
2. method calls in the view

Angular Tip:  We should avoid method calls in the view whenever possible, since they run on every $digest loop.

Thanks,